# Instanize java generic class whose constructor takes class object argument

Tags: java, generics

I have SuperQueue class

```
public class SuperQueue<E> implements Queue<E>{

SuperQueue(Class<? extends Queue<E>> subqClass) {}

}
```

How can I create a SuperQueue object? I have tried:

```
SuperQueue<Integer> superq = new SuperQueue<Integer> (ConcurrentLinkedQueue.class)
```

and

```
SuperQueue<Integer> superq = new SuperQueue<Integer> (ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Integer>.class)
```

Comment: You have to use a class that extends Queue. and not the class reference. Some thing like SuperQueue<Integer> superq = new SuperQueue<Integer> (new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Integer>())

Comment: Doesn't `new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Integer>()` create a queue object rather than a class object?

Comment: Yes the meaning of that line is the object that is passed should extend the class Queue.

Answer (score 1):

In your code

```
SuperQueue<Integer> superq = new SuperQueue<Integer>(ConcurrentLinkedQueue.class);
```

you are passing incompatible types because `Class<ConcurrentLinkedQueue>` cannot be converted to `Class<? extends Queue<Integer>`

In order to create the object, you need to pass a class that Implements `Queue<Integer>` for e.g.

```
class Foo implements Queue<Integer> {...}
```

and then you can use it like this

```
SuperQueue<Integer> superq = new SuperQueue<Integer>(Foo.class);
```

Comment: But why can't I pass `ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Integer>.class`? `ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Integer>` dose implement `Queue<Integer>`, like Foo in your example.

Comment: Because ConcurrentLinkedQueue<E> implements Queue<E> not Queue<Integer>

Comment: @Tim: Because there is only one ConcurrentLinkedQueue class object. There are no different ones for different type arguments.

Answer (score 0):

```
SuperQueue<Integer> superq =
    new SuperQueue<Integer>((Class<ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Integer>>)
                            (Class<?>)ConcurrentLinkedQueue.class);
```